# Why am I getting different time values in Tradingview when using PineScript

Tags: pine-script

From my understanding, the time variable in PineScript gives the UTC time of the current bar start. However, I am finding that it is sometimes giving the bar start time in UTC, and sometimes in another timezone. Here's a simple code snippet to show what I'm seeing:

```
//@version=4
study("Testing", shorttitle = "Test", overlay = true)
plot(hour(time), title="Hour")
```

When I run this script on an hourly chart, I should see the start hour of each bar in UTC. This works for some tickers like BTCUSD:Coinbase. However, for other tickers, like SPX, I am getting the start hour of the bar in UTC-5.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The time is in the exchange's time zone. See the [usrman page on time](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html).